# Select query code to return listitem value

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-2014

I am trying to type a select query code where listitem value result, but I got this error:

> Invalid column name 'adam'.

and I don't know what is the wrong with the code.

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpUDu.jpg

and this is the code:

```
private void listBox1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        label11.Text = "";
        t1.Text = "";
        t2.Text = "";
        t3.Text = "";
        t4.Text = "";
        t5.Text = "";
        t6.Text = "";
        t7.Text = "";
        t8.Text = "";
        cb2.Text = "";
        pb1.Image = null;
        con.Open();
        String sqlselectquery = "select * from employee where emp_id=" + listBox1.SelectedValue;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlselectquery, con);
       SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            t1.Text = (dr["emp_id"].ToString());
            t2.Text = (dr["emp_name"].ToString());
            t3.Text = (dr["emp_birth"].ToString());
            t4.Text = (dr["emp_id_code"].ToString());
            t5.Text = (dr["emp_add"].ToString());
            t6.Text = (dr["education"].ToString());
            t7.Text = (dr["hiredate"].ToString());
            t8.Text = (dr["salary"].ToString());
            cb1.SelectedValue = (dr["job_id"].ToString());
            cb2.Text = (dr["emp_rel"].ToString());
            byte[] img = (byte[])(dr["emp_pic"]);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(img);
            pb1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
        }
        con.Close();
    }
```

Comment: You dont't have  that column in your table?

Comment: Your image is not the same as the code you posted. It seems you are selecting a column in the query in your image that does not exist.

Comment: Please paste error text, as text, into your question. Screenshots of errors aren't very friendly for people who might try to answer your question.

Comment: @VladoPandžić the list value is a record in database not column ,my problem why the code reading it as column?

Comment: Deleted my answer as need more info. Does "Adam" exist in `listBox1.SelectedValue`? Is "Adam" the first value in the results?

Comment: @Lucax yes adam in listbox1 and the value of him in database is 1